# angularJS directive for href behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to get a href behavior added to  tag. How can this be done?
Is there way in angular directives to add same behavior to other html tags.

I have added

```
  <div click-element="#/page1/test?Tab=1/">
```

but i get the following lexer error for passing the URL as parameter:

```
 "stack": "Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#/page1/test?Tab=1/].
```

How can i pass the URL as attribute parameter?

**Updated**

I want the click-element directive to be the one which handles navigation. The element would rather look like:

```
<div click-element="#/page1/test?Tab=1/">
```

In click-element directive:

```
 function clickElement( $location) {

            var clickElementDefinition = {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    clickElement: "="
                },
                link: clickElementMethod
            };
            return clickElementDefinition ;

            function clickElementMethod(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (event) {
                        if (scope.clickElement) {
                        var arr = scope.clickElement.split("?");
                        var queryParam = arr[1].split("=") || "";
                        $location.path(arr[0]).search(queryParam[0], queryParam[1]);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

I still get the lexer error on directive load.

Comment: You don't need `#` in your own `ng-click="navigateTo('#/page1/test?Tab=1/')`. What does your `click-element` directive do (_code?_)?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VGl6MSrjX9LPXMutguCl?p=preview
The code works fine in this plunker, can you post the code of your directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either add a second set of quotes to the click-element or use attrs.clickElement instead of scope.

```
<div click-element="'#/page1/test?Tab=1/'">
```

or

```
function clickElementMethod(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (event) {
                    if (attrs.clickElement) {
                    var arr = attrs.clickElement.split("?");
                    var queryParam = arr[1].split("=") || "";
                    $location.path(arr[0]).search(queryParam[0], queryParam[1]);
                }
            });
        }
```

or

```
scope: {
     clickElement: "@"
},
```

Comment: Or use `clickElement: "@"`.

Comment: Good call. I reckon @ is probably a better way of doing it here.